# Store sensible data in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i'm making an appx for Windows Phone 8.1 and i need to store sensible data like username and password: it's my first windows app and i have no idea how to do this. Can you suggest a secure way to store these data?
Thanks
Fabio

Comment: Take a look at *PasswordVault* class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sqlite](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) for windows phone 8.1 and this is [Channel 9 Tutorial for Sqlite](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/19)